# log4js configure function error [NodeJs]

Tags: json, node.js, file, logging, log4js-node

I am getting the following error in console window when running my NodeJs application. I am using log4js for logging. Runtime platform is express.

**Error:**

```
undefined:1
?{
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ? in JSON at position 0
```

**Code:**

```
var log4js = require('log4js');
var mylog = log4js.configure('log4jsConfig.json');
logger = log4js.getLogger("absolute-logger");
```

**Config json:**

```
{
    "appenders": [
              {
            "type": "file",
            "absolute": true,
            "filename": "c:/temp/log_file.log",
            "maxLogSize": 20480,
            "backups": 10,
            "category": "absolute-logger"
        }
    ]
}
```

Question:
Any thoughts. I am thinking this is parsing error, but not sure how to resolve it.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you paste your code, config and error as separate blocks to make it easier to read?

Comment: undefined:1
?{
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ? in JSON at position 0

Comment: var log4js = require('log4js');
var mylog = log4js.configure('log4jsConfig.json');
logger = log4js.getLogger("absolute-logger");

Comment: In config file (log4jsConfig.json)
{
    "appenders": [
              {
            "type": "file",
            "absolute": true,
            "filename": "c:/temp/log_file.log",
            "maxLogSize": 20480,
            "backups": 10,
            "category": "absolute-logger"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Pasting in the comments doesn't help readability. Please edit your original post and make a separate code block for each part.

Comment: The code is in separate blocks.

Comment: sorry, If you read my original post it has three sections,**Error Message:**, **Code (in app.js)**, In config file (log4jsConfig.json)

Comment: I have edited your post for you - if this separation is not correct, please update it.

Comment: Thanks Duncanhall.

Comment: Try using a json parser to get the character at position 0. It could be that the editor you are using appends file identifiers. For instance, csv files created in the ubuntu libre text editor have a set of characters added to the beginning which make the file unusable for code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a windows system?  Sometimes, parsers get upset with \r\n  (carriage returns).  Try converting it UNIX (new line only) style lines.